# Holes in my Hibiscus

Tags: plant-health, hibiscus

[image]

I’m seeing holes like this on 4 separate Hibiscus plants. None on the other plants around them. Holes also on the buds. Any idea what’s causing it and how to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen snails or caterpillars?

Comment: I haven’t seen them. No.

Comment: How would I get rid of them if so?